# How to do list agregation with histogram in Open Graph?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I found in the documentation:

> List: Help highlight a user's recent activity or favorite objects. Lists also have an associated histogram, shaded grey, that will automatically appear for each row displayed in the list.

But how to do histogram in list?

Answer (score 1):

You don't 'do' the histogram, it's displayed in shaded blocks behind the list automatically when your published actions are displayed on a user's timeline in the aggregation units

See attached from my profile:

[image: aggregation in list format with histogram]

Answer (score 1):

Your aggregation should contain {count} or some other aggregate unit in Caption Lines.

For example:
{count} times

After that list will become histogram.